# How to save 3d arrays in Matlab that are generated in a loop?

Tags: image, matlab, 3d

I'm reading in 3d arrays, subtracting all of them from one of them, and trying to save the results as the same type of arrays. They are all equal sizes to each other, 1888x3520x6.

Here is the piece of code that I have:

```
 [FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.x3d*','MultiSelect','on'); 
 numfiles = size(FileName,2); 
 FileName{1} 
 entirefile1 =fullfile(PathName,FileName{1})
 Im1 = x3dread(entirefile1);
 for j = 2:numfiles
   FileName{j} 
   entirefile2 =fullfile(PathName,FileName{j})
   Im2 = x3dread(entirefile2); 

   J = num2str(j);
   strcat('ImDelta', J);
   ImDelta = imsubtract(Im1, Im2);

 end
```

I see that I'm creating a character sring by using strcat. But I'm not making it into a new file name. Only one file is resulting at the end of the loop. 
(x3dread function is similar to "load" for working with images, only it is specifically written to handle the type of the 3dimention files that I have.)
Any help is appreciated. I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Please indicate which line you think saves the image? I'm guessing you're missing a call to `x3dsave` or a similar function to *actually* save the images.

Comment: When the code executes, ImDelta is not empty, has somethign in it. That makes me believe that an 3d image is already created. But I will check if x3dsave or similar needs ti be used.

Comment: Yes the *variable* `ImDelta` exists but it gets replaced every loop iteration. If you want to save all of these variables, then you'll want to store `ImDelta` as a cell array where you use `ImDelta{j} = imsubtract(Im1, Im2)`. Then afterwards you will have access to all images.

Comment: Thank you Suever your comments were very helpful. What I actually needed to add to the same loop was save([entirefile2 'ImDelta.mat'],'ImDelta');

Comment: @Suever I'll reopen the question so you can answer it.  Seems the duplicate I've marked is unrelated.... that's what happens when the OP actually provides the correct details in the question after I've closed it :)